# How to prevent Android Studio 2.0 from running on same device

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.0

With the new update of Android Studio, whenever I rebuild my app, it always launches it on the same emulator/device. In order for me to switch devices, I have to shutdown the emulator/disconnect the device, so that it brings up the device selection screen.

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me I had to press the red stop button in order to stop the "instant run" mode which automatically runs your app on the same device.

[image]

Once I press the stop button I can run the app again and it will bring up the device chooser dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

[Select this menu:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SY5QX.png)

And then uncheck the "Use the same device.." option:

[Uncheck thi option:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1Pe8.png)

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: did you see those pictures? on my comment?

Comment: now i know. They (stackoverflow) say that i need a reputation about 10 to post images. sorry.

Comment: I looked at the pictures in your post and followed the instructions. It did not work.